# Obtaining coordinates from a Line at X distance

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I'm working on a small personal project using GeoServer and OpenLayers.

At the moment I have various LineStrings/MultiLineStrings that represent the roads of a city. I want to know if I'd be able to get the coordinates obtained from one of these roads (Lines) after moving through it (the line) X distance.

For example if the road/line has a total distance of 1000 meters, what's the coordinate of the line after traversing 300 meters.

Comment: `geometry.getCoordinateAt(300/1000)` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_LineString-LineString.html#getCoordinateAt  For a MultiLineString you would first need to determine which component LineString included the required distance.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works